# Kubuntu 19.10 (sddm) won't load since kernel update

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu

Since the Linux kernel was updated to version 5.3.0-24 on my Kubuntu system, it doesn't start up. All I see is a black screen with my cursor:

- the cursor doesn't move;
- the cursor is breeze-themed, so some KDE things are able to load;
- I am unable to switch to tty2,3,...;
- the keyboard seems unresponsive, although its backlight works.

Things work perfectly if I choose kernel version 5.3.0-23 in the GRUB menu.

First I thought that the issue was related to kubuntu-backports, so I purged that PPA, and reverted to the "standard" KDE version.

My second guess was that the problem was with the nvidia-driver (version 440, installed from the official NVIDIA PPA), so I reverted that too (by again purging the PPA). Now it's on version 435, from the `ubuntu-drivers-common` package.

So my installation right now is fairly "vanilla", still, the system won't load with kernel ...-24, only with ...-23.

Then I thought that the issue is with the kernel itself since I saw the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.3.0-26.28/changelog) entry for the then-upcoming kernel version ...-26:

> - nvidia-435 is in eoan, linux-restricted-modules only builds
>     against 430,
>     ubiquity gives me the self-signed modules experience instead of using the
>     Canonical-signed modules (LP: #1856407)
>
>   - Add nvidia-435 dkms build

So I've waited for the new kernel release which happened lately, I updated the things, yet my system won't load with the new kernel ...-26 either.

Could you suggest some steps to resolve this issue, other than a full reinstallation of my system?

Which packages should I purge/reinstall, in what order, etc.?

**EDIT 1:**

I believe that the cited changelog entry is related to the `linux-restricted-modules` source package, and there is a `linux-modules-nvidia-435-generic` binary package in the repo related to that. It depends on the `linux-image-...` itself, but it is not installed, and it is not installed by the `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command either.
Note: installing it did not resolve the issue.

**EDIT 2:**

Purging every Nvidia-related stuff, and installing `nvidia-driver-430` does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial-and-error, one possible combination of steps which resulted in a working system (for me, at least):

1. `sudo apt purge *nvidia*`

   - The above may be too much if someone works with a lot of Nvidia-related stuff. Purging the `nvidia-driver-XXX` only may be sufficient but I didn't test it.
2. `reboot`
3. in the GRUB menu choosing the *latest* kernel (which was unfunctional till now)

   - Now, I was able to start-up KDE/sddm without the proprietary Nvidia driver/packages.
4. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

   - Now, the *latest* proprietary driver is installed, and I could reboot the system without any issue.